# Как добавить переменные в модель формы?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть база данных, в ней две таблицы:

1. Table1
2. Table2

В `Table2` есть строки: `id и Name`.

На сайте есть две страницы:

1. Главная страница
2. Страница Add

На странице Add есть форма, в которой есть input,  с помощью этой формы я добавляю записи в table2.
С этой страницей всё ок.

Задача с главной страницей.
Тут есть форма, какая ее суть:
Я получаю из таблицы table2 первую запись, например там будет Name1
В форме создаю checkbox с именем Name1 и так по кругу, пока есть записи в таблице table2.
Вот код формы на Yii2

```
<?php foreach($allNameEx as $nameEx) : ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, $nameEx['name'])->checkbox() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
```

`$model` - это `$model = new form();`

`$allNameEx` - это массив который достает все записи Name из table2.

Этот код работал бы, но при создании формы на странице, есть файл модели формы, в котором нужно добавлять переменные такие же, как и в input формы.
Если  `<?= $form->field($model, $nameEx['name'])->checkbox() ?>` это будет, например `<?= $form->field($model, 'Name1')->checkbox() ?>`, то в модели формы соответственно должна быть переменная public $Name1.
Вот и вопрос, как добавлять в модель формы эти переменные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заработало,

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'nameEx[]')->checkboxList(form::checkFormData()); ?>
```